# Get specified array inside codeigniter cart session

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session, cart

Is there a way to get a specified array inside codeigniter's cart session?

for example i have these values

```
Array
(
    [c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 1000
            [name] => Pin 
            [subtotal] => 1000
        )

    [c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 3
            [price] => 100
            [name] => Amber
            [subtotal] => 300
        )

)
```

and i only want to get the values for the array "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b"

i tried

```
$this->session->userdata("c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c");
```

and

```
$this->cart->contents("c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c");
```

but it didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get your cart items with `$this->cart->contents()` to get a specific key, just call like this.

```
$getCartItem = 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b';
$cartItems = $this->cart->contents();

if( isset($cartItems[$getCartItem]) ) 
{
    $item = $cartItems[$getCartItem];
    // do stuff

} else {
    //not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function like that,

```
 public function getCartInfo($rowId)
    {

        $cart = $this->cart->contents();
        if( isset($cart[$rowId])) //your $rowId="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c"
        {
            $data = $cart[$rowId];
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($data); //view specific cart information
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "not found";
        }
        exit();
    }
```